# select2 is not updated after disable of selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I'm trying to disable the selected option in select2 but it seems like the select2 is not refreshing.

My purpose is to disable each item in the select2 list after selecting it. I see the HTML that the option got the disabled attribute but the option is still enabled in the select2 element.

```
$("#select-filter").select2({
    placeholder: "Select a category",
    data:[{
        id: "",
        text: ""
    },{
        id: "project",
        text: "project"
    },{
        id: "date",
        text: "date"
    },{
        id: "user",
        text: "user"
    }]
}).on("change", function(e) {
    $("#select-filter :selected").attr("disabled", "true");
});
```

See example : https://jsfiddle.net/bkqeqbay/1/

Comment: which browser are you using ? --- try              `$("#select-filter :selected").prop("disabled", true);`

Comment: @Amani chrome , and already tried that - didn't help

Comment: i tried your code with chrome and its working -- https://jsfiddle.net/bkqeqbay/

Comment: @Amani you didnt load the correct select2 files . please see https://jsfiddle.net/bkqeqbay/1/

Comment: `"true"` is a string not a Boolean.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the select event and the data like so:

```
...}).on("select2:select", function(e) {
  console.dir(e.params.data);
  e.params.data.disabled = true;
});
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bkqeqbay/4/

Note that if you must also disable the underlying select element option you can do:

```
 var index = $(e.params.data.element).index();
 $("#select-filter").find('option').eq(index).prop('disabled',true);
```